# Photoshop Rotate & Export?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

I have a single image in Photoshop, and I'm trying to create a flip-book animation. I'd like to do the following 90 times:

- "Save for Web" and save as a PNG (numbered 01 through 90)
- Rotate the (only) layer in the canvas by one degree

This way, I would expect to see 90 minutes with the single source image rotated 1 through 90 degrees.

I've tried creating some Actions to do this, but it seems to get hung up on the idea of incrementing the file names. I've learned that Automate->Batch may help with this, but the issue there seems to be using ONE source image and repeating the "rotate by one degree" step of the action multiple times.

Could someone give me some clear tips / guidelines on how I might achieve this goal?

Comment: Does to have to be photoshop? Why not export from flash/after effects as s png sequence?

Comment: I don't own that software, so yup, needs to be Photoshop in this instance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try another approach:

1. Create an action that does your rotation by duplicating the layer below, rotating it and showing it in a layer comp.
2. Play the action again and again until you got an amount of layer comps as frames you need
3. Use the "layer comps to file" script and export the layer comps to png

Answer (score 0):

as a grunt method, you could simply create the single action as you need:

- Rotate the layer.
- Save for web.
- name the file with the dialog box.

Then create an action where you "record" playing that action 10 times. This new action will move the item 10 degrees, and save the new file each time. Now record playing this NEW action nine times.

By nesting the actions you can step through the sequence once, ten times, or 90 times.